# numpy: broadcast multiplication over one common axis of two 2d arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, optimization

I'm looking for a way to element-wise multiply two 2d arrays of shape (a, b) and (b, c), respectively. Over the 'b' axis, which the two arrays have in common.

For instance, an example of what I'd like to broadcast (vectorize) is:

```
import numpy as np    

# some dummy data
A = np.empty((2, 3))
B = np.empty((3, 4))

# naive implementation
C = np.vstack(np.kron(A[:, i], B[i, :]) for i in [0, 1, 2])

# this should give (3, 2, 4)
C.shape
```

Does anyone know what to do here? Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***credit to @hpaulj for the definitions of `A` and `B`***
use `np.outer` and `np.stack`

```
A = np.arange(6).reshape((2, 3))
B = np.arange(12).reshape((3, 4))

np.stack([np.outer(A[:, i], B[i, :]) for i in range(A.shape[1])])

[[[ 0  0  0  0]
  [ 0  3  6  9]]

 [[ 4  5  6  7]
  [16 20 24 28]]

 [[16 18 20 22]
  [40 45 50 55]]]
```

---

and to get the `np.einsum` in the correct shape

```
np.einsum('ij, jk->jik', A, B)

[[[ 0  0  0  0]
  [ 0  3  6  9]]

 [[ 4  5  6  7]
  [16 20 24 28]]

 [[16 18 20 22]
  [40 45 50 55]]]
```

---

Broadcasting and `transpose`

```
(A[:, None] * B.T).transpose(2, 0, 1)

[[[ 0  0  0  0]
  [ 0  3  6  9]]

 [[ 4  5  6  7]
  [16 20 24 28]]

 [[16 18 20 22]
  [40 45 50 55]]]
```

---

***shape is `(3, 2, 4)`***

***timing***
[image]

Comment: @piRSuared Thanks so much, even with benchmarks.. awesome.

Answer (score 3):

With different test cases:

```
In [56]: A=np.arange(6).reshape((2,3))
In [57]: B=np.arange(12).reshape((3,4))
In [58]: np.vstack([np.kron(A[:,i],B[i,:]) for i in range(3)])
Out[58]: 
array([[ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  3,  6,  9],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7, 16, 20, 24, 28],
       [16, 18, 20, 22, 40, 45, 50, 55]])
```

A first try with `einsum, preserving all 3 axes (no summing)

```
In [60]: np.einsum('ij,jk->ijk',A,B)
Out[60]: 
array([[[ 0,  0,  0,  0],
        [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
        [16, 18, 20, 22]],

       [[ 0,  3,  6,  9],
        [16, 20, 24, 28],
        [40, 45, 50, 55]]])
```

Same numbers, but in a different shape.

I can reorder axes on output, to make a 2x4x3, which can be reshaped to 8,3 and transposed.

```
In [64]: np.einsum('ij,jk->ikj',A,B).reshape(8,3).T
Out[64]: 
array([[ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  3,  6,  9],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7, 16, 20, 24, 28],
       [16, 18, 20, 22, 40, 45, 50, 55]])
```

So with another iteration I can get rid of the transpose

```
In [68]: np.einsum('ij,jk->jik',A,B).reshape(3,8)
Out[68]: 
array([[ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  3,  6,  9],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7, 16, 20, 24, 28],
       [16, 18, 20, 22, 40, 45, 50, 55]])
```

I should have gotten there right away.  `A` is (2,3), `B` is (3,4), and I want (3,2,4) reshaped to (3,8).  i=2, j=3, k=4 => jik.

So another way of describing the problem,

```
a_ij * b_jk = c_jik
```

And since I'm not making use of the `sum` part of the `einsum`, regular broadcasted multiplication will also work, with one or more transposes.

Comment: Thanks so much.. I didn't know that `np.einsum` could handle these situations too